# MS Exchange "modern authentication" support for EMAIL for java

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, office365

I have been asked to upgrade the java code to support modern authentication (which currently supports basic auth) for MS Exchange used to send email from server. I have clientid, tenantid, and client secret already with me. I have scrolled and went thru many articles on web, I got the understanding of oAuth2 and flow of what needs to be done, but I am unable to actually find the java libraries for the purpose. Any help, tutorial links or sample code will help.

Went thru this article : [https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2#:~:text=Starting%20with%20JavaMail%201.5.,use%20only%20the%20XOAUTH2%20mechanism](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2#:%7E:text=Starting%20with%20JavaMail%201.5.,use%20only%20the%20XOAUTH2%20mechanism).
but the link for ms server does not proivde require info

Comment: Not sure if you finished this already but I think you might be looking for the microsoft graph mail api if you want to send emails programmatically. Here's the link to the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Maybe you mean this, actually https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/outlook-for-ios-and-android/setup-with-modern-authentication

Answer (score 0):

The lib for ews is `ews-java-api`
The example how to use Modern flow:

1. Get token with scope - https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All
2. Add the token to headers:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
service.setUrl(URI.create("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx"));
service.getHttpHeaders().put("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth